# Identify Webpage

Tags: python, html, extract

Hi I am trying to parse a webpage in Python. This webpage is in a restricted area so I can not give the link. In this webpage you can do queries which then are published in a table which is added on the same webpage, but with new url. When I parse the page I get everything except the table.

I have noticed that it does not matter how my queries are, the url is always the same. So I always get the same result from my parser, which is the webpage without the query result (the table). But if I inspect the webpage (in Chrome) then the table and its results is included in the HTML. My parser just look like this:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.home_page.com") as url:
    s = url.read()
#I'm guessing this would output the html source code?
print(s)
```

Then my question, are there some other way to identify the webpage so I will receive everything that is published on the webpage?

Comment: Is there some client-side scripting going on to generate/retrieve the table? What happens if you disable javascript in your browser and attempt to access the web page?

Comment: Thanks for the intrest, I just put conditions into a HTML form and the press search, and the table is generated.

Comment: Right. Your python code simply reads the raw string data coming from the HTTP request. It does not have the capability to execute any client side scripts that may be in the page. Your browser, on the other hand, will "run" the page and execute any scripts that are valid. You need to use a browser automation tool such as Selenium to get the content you want.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

Comment: Thanks you Joel Cornett!, I am taking look at Selenium and hopefully can work something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will based on your question i think you are looking up for web scraping techniques

will here is what i'm suggesting
you could use regular expressing to get data that can be expressed in specific  patterns
for example

```
import urllib,re
siteContent  = urllib.urlopen("http://example.com").read()
GetBoldWords = re.findall(r"<b>[\w\d ]+",siteContent)
print "Bold Words are :"
print getBoldWords
```

so in this case you have to learn more about regex `(regular expression)` and get your own pattern

in some specific cases you might have to deal with Client Side  (for example you have to submit query's through pop up pages from `javascript` or you have to ignore some `alert` from `javascript` then you have to use web browsers api , you could use `Selenium` to deal with this kind of issues